# Unity light not showing up over background sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

I have a power-up GameObject with a light component attached to it.

The sprite shows up fine, however, the halo effect does not work when the GameObject is placed over another sprite (eg a background wall).

[image: Power-up]

I think its a problem with the material (as I have tried other things such as changing the culling mask, ordering layer, etc) - however, I don't know which properties to change in order to make the light visible.

I am using an area light.

[image: Light]

Comment: I would suggest not using baked lights. I believe the `Light` component being a 3d object, its z position matters very much.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I saw correctly your game is 2D. If so, check out [2D Lights](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.lightweight@6.7/manual/2DLightProperties.html)